# How to find out if 2 triangles on a 2D plane rotated in 3D space are intersecting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a method in C# and unity, that takes in 2 triangles(the positions of their vertices) and returns true if the triangles are touching(not jammed into each other, just properly aligned and touching), and false if they are not. I divided it into tests, they must have opposite normals, they must be on the same 2D plane(which may be rotated), and must be intersecting on that 2D plane. How do I do that last step?

```
bool TrianglesTouching(Vector3[] triangle1, Vector3[] triangle2)
{
    bool touching = false;

    // Step 1: Success
    bool facing = false;
    Vector3 normal1 = SurfaceNormal(triangle1[0], triangle1[1], triangle1[2]);
    Vector3 normal2 = SurfaceNormal(triangle2[0], triangle2[1], triangle2[2]);
    facing = Util.RoundVector3(normal1, 0.0001f) == Util.RoundVector3(normal2 * -1f, 0.0001f);

    // Step 2: Success
    bool onSamePlane = false;
    Plane plane = new Plane();
    plane.Set3Points(triangle1[0], triangle1[1], triangle1[2]);
    onSamePlane = Util.RoundToNearest(plane.GetDistanceToPoint(triangle2[0]), 0.0001f) == 0f; // point 0 is an arbitrary vertex of the triangle, we could have found the position of the triangle by averaging the position of its vertices, but that isnt necessary in this case. Any vertex position of this triangle will do just fine.

    // Step 3: What do I do here?
    bool intersectingOnPlane = false;
    // Some logic to figure out if they're intersecting. Please fill this in for me, StackOverflow wizards.

    touching = facing && onSamePlane && intersectingOnPlane;
    return touching;
}
```

---

Diagram of what I mean:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB6LZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Habrador - Use math to solve problems in Unity with C# - Chapter 6 Are two triangles in 2D space intersecting?](https://www.habrador.com/tutorials/math/6-triangle-triangle-intersection). Really check it out since it explains it way more details there.

Basically it approaches this in the classical 3 steps:

> - **Step 1.** Approximate the triangles with rectangles and test if they intersect.
> - **Step 2.** Check if any of the sides of one triangle is intersecting with any of the sides of the other triangle.
> - **Step 3.** Check if any of the corners of one triangle is inside the other triangle, and vice versa.

First it uses some helper types

> ```
> //To store triangle data to get cleaner code
> public struct Triangle
> {
>     //Corners of the triangle
>     public Vector3 p1, p2, p3;
>     //The 3 line segments that make up this triangle
>     public LineSegment[] lineSegments;
>
>     public Triangle(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3)
>     {
>         this.p1 = p1;
>         this.p2 = p2;
>         this.p3 = p3;
>
>         lineSegments = new LineSegment[3];
>
>         lineSegments[0] = new LineSegment(p1, p2);
>         lineSegments[1] = new LineSegment(p2, p3);
>         lineSegments[2] = new LineSegment(p3, p1);
>     }
> }
>
> //To create a line segment
> public struct LineSegment
> {
>     //Start/end coordinates
>     public Vector3 p1, p2;
>
>     public LineSegment(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
>     {
>         this.p1 = p1;
>         this.p2 = p2;
>     }
> }
> ```

And then it checks the 3 steps consecutive in

> ```
> //The triangle-triangle intersection in 2D algorithm
> bool IsTriangleTriangleIntersecting(Triangle triangle1, Triangle triangle2)
> {
>     bool isIntersecting = false;
>
>     //Step 1. AABB intersection
>     if (IsIntersectingAABB(triangle1, triangle2))
>     {
>         //Step 2. Line segment - triangle intersection
>         if (AreAnyLineSegmentsIntersecting(triangle1, triangle2))
>         {
>             isIntersecting = true;
>         }
>         //Step 3. Point in triangle intersection - if one of the triangles is inside the other
>         else if (AreCornersIntersecting(triangle1, triangle2))
>         {
>             isIntersecting = true;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return isIntersecting;
> }
> ```

The implementation of the 3 steps itself

> ```
> //
> // STEP 1 - Intersection: AABB
> //
>
> //Approximate the triangles with rectangles and see if they intersect with the AABB intersection algorithm
> bool IsIntersectingAABB(Triangle t1, Triangle t2)
> {
>   //Find the size of the bounding box
>
>   //Triangle 1
>   float t1_minX = Mathf.Min(t1.p1.x, Mathf.Min(t1.p2.x, t1.p3.x));
>   float t1_maxX = Mathf.Max(t1.p1.x, Mathf.Max(t1.p2.x, t1.p3.x));
>   float t1_minZ = Mathf.Min(t1.p1.z, Mathf.Min(t1.p2.z, t1.p3.z));
>   float t1_maxZ = Mathf.Max(t1.p1.z, Mathf.Max(t1.p2.z, t1.p3.z));
>
>   //Triangle 2
>   float t2_minX = Mathf.Min(t2.p1.x, Mathf.Min(t2.p2.x, t2.p3.x));
>   float t2_maxX = Mathf.Max(t2.p1.x, Mathf.Max(t2.p2.x, t2.p3.x));
>   float t2_minZ = Mathf.Min(t2.p1.z, Mathf.Min(t2.p2.z, t2.p3.z));
>   float t2_maxZ = Mathf.Max(t2.p1.z, Mathf.Max(t2.p2.z, t2.p3.z));
>
>
>   //Are the rectangles intersecting?
>   //If the min of one box in one dimension is greater than the max of another box then the boxes are not intersecting
>   //They have to intersect in 2 dimensions. We have to test if box 1 is to the left or box 2 and vice versa
>   bool isIntersecting = true;
>
>   //X axis
>   if (t1_minX > t2_maxX)
>   {
>       isIntersecting = false;
>   }
>   else if (t2_minX > t1_maxX)
>   {
>       isIntersecting = false;
>   }
>   //Z axis
>   else if (t1_minZ > t2_maxZ)
>   {
>       isIntersecting = false;
>   }
>   else if (t2_minZ > t1_maxZ)
>   {
>       isIntersecting = false;
>   }
>
>
>   //Debugging to display the approximated rectangles
>   //Box 1
>   Vector3 BB_1_centerPos = new Vector3((t1_maxX - t1_minX) * 0.5f + t1_minX, -0.2f, (t1_maxZ - t1_minZ) * 0.5f + t1_minZ);
>
>   box1Obj.transform.position = BB_1_centerPos;
>
>   box1Obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(t1_maxX - t1_minX, 0.1f, t1_maxZ - t1_minZ);
>
>   //Box 2
>   Vector3 BB_2_centerPos = new Vector3((t2_maxX - t2_minX) * 0.5f + t2_minX, -0.2f, (t2_maxZ - t2_minZ) * 0.5f + t2_minZ);
>
>   box2Obj.transform.position = BB_2_centerPos;
>
>   box2Obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(t2_maxX - t2_minX, 0.1f, t2_maxZ - t2_minZ);
>
>
>   return isIntersecting;
> }
>
> //
> // STEP 2 - Intersection: Line segment - triangle
> //
>
> //Check if any of the edges that make up one of the triangles is intersecting with any of
> //the edges of the other triangle
> bool AreAnyLineSegmentsIntersecting(Triangle t1, Triangle t2)
> {
>   bool isIntersecting = false;
>
>   //Loop through all edges
>   for (int i = 0; i < t1.lineSegments.Length; i++)
>   {
>       for (int j = 0; j < t2.lineSegments.Length; j++)
>       {
>           //The start/end coordinates of the current line segments
>           Vector3 t1_p1 = t1.lineSegments[i].p1;
>           Vector3 t1_p2 = t1.lineSegments[i].p2;
>           Vector3 t2_p1 = t2.lineSegments[j].p1;
>           Vector3 t2_p2 = t2.lineSegments[j].p2;
>
>           //Are they intersecting?
>           if (AreLineSegmentsIntersecting(t1_p1, t1_p2, t2_p1, t2_p2))
>           {
>               isIntersecting = true;
>
>               //To stop the outer for loop
>               i = int.MaxValue - 1;
>
>               break;
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
>   return isIntersecting;
> }
>
> //Check if 2 line segments are intersecting in 2d space
> //http://thirdpartyninjas.com/blog/2008/10/07/line-segment-intersection/
> //p1 and p2 belong to line 1, p3 and p4 belong to line 2
> bool AreLineSegmentsIntersecting(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3, Vector3 p4)
> {
>   bool isIntersecting = false;
>
>   float denominator = (p4.z - p3.z) * (p2.x - p1.x) - (p4.x - p3.x) * (p2.z - p1.z);
>
>   //Make sure the denominator is != 0, if 0 the lines are parallel
>   if (denominator != 0)
>   {
>       float u_a = ((p4.x - p3.x) * (p1.z - p3.z) - (p4.z - p3.z) * (p1.x - p3.x)) / denominator;
>       float u_b = ((p2.x - p1.x) * (p1.z - p3.z) - (p2.z - p1.z) * (p1.x - p3.x)) / denominator;
>
>       //Is intersecting if u_a and u_b are between 0 and 1
>       if (u_a >= 0 && u_a <= 1 && u_b >= 0 && u_b <= 1)
>       {
>           isIntersecting = true;
>       }
>   }
>
>   return isIntersecting;
> }
>
> //
> // STEP 3 - Intersection: Point in triangle
> //
>
> //There's a possibility that one of the triangles is smaller than the other
> //So we have to check if any of the triangle's corners is inside the other triangle
> bool AreCornersIntersecting(Triangle t1, Triangle t2)
> {
>   bool isIntersecting = false;
>
>   //We only have to test one corner from each triangle
>   //Triangle 1 in triangle 2
>   if (IsPointInTriangle(t1.p1, t2.p1, t2.p2, t2.p3))
>   {
>       isIntersecting = true;
>   }
>   //Triangle 2 in triangle 1
>   else if (IsPointInTriangle(t2.p1, t1.p1, t1.p2, t1.p3))
>   {
>       isIntersecting = true;
>   }
>
>   return isIntersecting;
> }
>
>
>
> //Is a point p inside a triangle p1-p2-p3?
> //From http://totologic.blogspot.se/2014/01/accurate-point-in-triangle-test.html
> bool IsPointInTriangle(Vector3 p, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3)
> {
>   bool isWithinTriangle = false;
>
>   float denominator = ((p2.z - p3.z) * (p1.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (p1.z - p3.z));
>
>   float a = ((p2.z - p3.z) * (p.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (p.z - p3.z)) / denominator;
>   float b = ((p3.z - p1.z) * (p.x - p3.x) + (p1.x - p3.x) * (p.z - p3.z)) / denominator;
>   float c = 1 - a - b;
>
>   //The point is within the triangle if 0 <= a <= 1 and 0 <= b <= 1 and 0 <= c <= 1
>   if (a >= 0f && a <= 1f && b >= 0f && b <= 1f && c >= 0f && c <= 1f)
>   {
>       isWithinTriangle = true;
>   }
>
>   return isWithinTriangle;
> }
> ```

---

Soooo I decided to rework and refactor this a little

```
/// <summary>
/// To store triangle data to get cleaner code
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public struct Triangle2D
{
    /// <summary>
    /// To create a line segment
    /// </summary>
    private struct LineSegment2D
    {
        //Start/end coordinates
        private readonly Vector2 _p1;
        private readonly Vector2 _p2;

        public LineSegment2D(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2)
        {
            _p1 = p1;
            _p2 = p2;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if 2 line segments are intersecting in 2d space
        /// <para>http://thirdpartyninjas.com/blog/2008/10/07/line-segment-intersection/</para>
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsIntersecting(LineSegment2D other)
        {
            var p3 = other._p1;
            var p4 = other._p2;

            var denominator = (p4.y - p3.y) * (_p2.x - _p1.x) - (p4.x - p3.x) * (_p2.y - _p1.y);

            //Make sure the denominator is != 0, if 0 the lines are parallel
            if (denominator == 0) return false;

            var u_a = ((p4.x - p3.x) * (_p1.y - p3.y) - (p4.y - p3.y) * (_p1.x - p3.x)) / denominator;
            var u_b = ((_p2.x - _p1.x) * (_p1.y - p3.y) - (_p2.y - _p1.y) * (_p1.x - p3.x)) / denominator;

            //Is intersecting if u_a and u_b are between 0 and 1
            return 0 <= u_a && u_a <= 1 && 0 <= u_b && u_b <= 1;
        }
    }

    //Corners of the triangle
    // Can be edited via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _a;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _b;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _c;

    //The 3 line segments that make up this triangle
    private LineSegment2D[] _lineSegments;

    public Triangle2D(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;

        _lineSegments = new[]
        {
            new LineSegment2D(a, b),
            new LineSegment2D(b, c),
            new LineSegment2D(c, a)
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is this triangle intersecting the other one?
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsIntersecting(Triangle2D other)
    {
        //Step 1. AABB intersection
        if (IsIntersectingAABB(other))
        {
            //Step 2. Line segment - triangle intersection
            if (AreAnyLineSegmentsIntersecting(other))
            {
                return true;
            }

            //Step 3. Point in triangle intersection - if one of the triangles is inside the other
            if (AreCornersIntersecting(other))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is a point p inside this triangle
    ///<para>From http://totologic.blogspot.se/2014/01/accurate-point-in-triangle-test.html</para>
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsPointInTriangle(Vector2 p)
    {
        var denominator = (_b.y - _c.y) * (_a.x - _c.x) + (_c.x - _b.x) * (_a.y - _c.y);

        var a = ((_b.y - _c.y) * (p.x - _c.x) + (_c.x - _b.x) * (p.y - _c.y)) / denominator;
        var b = ((_c.y - _a.y) * (p.x - _c.x) + (_a.x - _c.x) * (p.y - _c.y)) / denominator;
        var c = 1 - a - b;

        return 0f <= a && a <= 1f && 0f <= b && b <= 1f && 0f <= c && c <= 1f;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Approximate the triangles with rectangles and see if they intersect with the AABB intersection algorithm
    /// </summary>
    private bool IsIntersectingAABB(Triangle2D other)
    {
        //Find the size of the bounding boxes

        // Bounding box Triangle 1
        var t1_minX = Mathf.Min(_a.x, _b.x, _c.x);
        var t1_maxX = Mathf.Max(_a.x, _b.x, _c.x);
        var t1_minY = Mathf.Min(_a.y, _b.y, _c.y);
        var t1_maxY = Mathf.Max(_a.y, _b.y, _c.y);

        // Bounding box Triangle 2
        var t2_minX = Mathf.Min(other._a.x, other._b.x, other._c.x);
        var t2_maxX = Mathf.Max(other._a.x, other._b.x, other._c.x);
        var t2_minY = Mathf.Min(other._a.y, other._b.y, other._c.y);
        var t2_maxY = Mathf.Max(other._a.y, other._b.y, other._c.y);

        //Are the rectangles intersecting?
        //If the min of one box in one dimension is greater than the max of another box then the boxes are not intersecting
        //They have to intersect in 2 dimensions. We have to test if box 1 is to the left or box 2 and vice versa

        return t1_minX <= t2_maxX && t2_minX <= t1_maxX && t1_minY <= t2_maxY && t2_minY <= t1_maxY;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if any of the edges that make up one of the triangles is intersecting with any of the edges of the other triangle
    /// </summary>
    private bool AreAnyLineSegmentsIntersecting(Triangle2D triangle2)
    {
        //Loop through all edges
        foreach (var line1 in _lineSegments)
        {
            foreach (var line2 in triangle2._lineSegments)
            {
                //Are they intersecting?
                if (line1.IsIntersecting(line2))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// There's a possibility that one of the triangles is smaller than the other
    /// <para>So we have to check if any of the triangle's corners is inside the other triangle</para>
    /// </summary>
    private bool AreCornersIntersecting(Triangle2D other)
    {
        //We only have to test one corner from each triangle (otherwise the line segments would already intersect anyway)
        //Triangle 1 in triangle 2 or //Triangle 2 in triangle 1
        return other.IsPointInTriangle(_a) || IsPointInTriangle(other._a);
    }
}
```

And finally the usage would be e.g.

```
// Create the two triangles structs
var triangle1 = new Triangle2D(triangle1[0], triangle1[1], triangle1[2]);
var triangle2 = new Triangle2D(triangle2[0], triangle2[1], triangle2[2]);

bool intersectingOnPlane = triangle1.IsIntersecting(triangle2);
```

Comment: Hmm. I want this to return false if they're not actually aligned and just jammed into each other. Does this method do that?

Comment: This method returns true if the triangles are at any point intersecting as the question title asks ;)

Comment: So you're saying if the triangles are intersecting but not actually facing each other, the method will still return true? I don't want that. The triangles need to be facing. And by "facing", I mean they have opposite surface normals.

Comment: Can't you simply test this independently?

Comment: Oh, I guess. Thanks. I'll still consider just completing my own method, though. This seems very long and complex.

Comment: Well what I showed you is where you commented `Step 3: What do I do here?` ;) Your other checks you can / have to still do ... see updated usage at the bottom

Comment: I'm still not 100% satisfied. This method seems so long and unnecessarily complicated. I have a concern for performance because I'm gonna be looping a WHOLE LOT of triangles, calling my TrianglesTouching() method.

Comment: @IbrahimDDeveloper well, you might be lucky and someone might add another solution .. but currently I'm pretty sure you can't really get more efficient while keeping the same precision ;) if you have so many triangles you could still go multithreading